# I specify node version in package.json, Azure tells me to specify version in my package.json

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

From my package.json:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "==0.10.21"
},
```

Every single time I run `git push azure master`

> Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.17, 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21.
>   Selected node.js version 0.10.21. Use package.json file to choose a
>   different version.

Is Azure broken or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried without the ==, i.e., "node": "0.10.21"?

Comment: @TomGrant I have - same message.

Comment: Sounds like just a comment (it *says* it's going to use `0.10.21`), not an error.